# How to determine what cause Apache to hang after 5 minutes online on ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, php

Good Morning, please help me to solve what is causing hang on my server

Primary Server Specification

- ProLiant-DL320e-Gen8 RAM : 32GB DDR3
- PROCESSOR : Intel® Xeon(R) CPU  E3-1220 V2 @ 3.10GHz × 4
- OS : UBUNTU DESKTOP 16.04 64 BIT HD : 1TB

We have web based applications. The first one, SIAO, it is an attendance management system. We use solution X-320S fingerprint machine to record attendance at 84 office (3500 employees) and there is a local server on every office. the local server's tasks are to download the attendance logs and send them to the primary server

We also have performance reporting system (Web based application too), it is called E-Kinerja. 3500 employees must report what they did today or yesterday, and their boss must verify it, it is true or not. And the report system will do some calculations to calculate how much bonus salary a month they will get from their attendance rate and performance report.

And we also have an employees data management system, it is called SIMPEG-DMS. At every office there is an operator to update data about employee. Personal data like Name, Age, Gender, Birthday, Address, etc and then their education data, their employment history and employment level, their health insurance data, their tax data, their family data (wife/husband, child), their individual certification/ individual training data. The operator will input all of that and will upload scanned documents about that

The problem is my server crash after 5 minutes online. It will freeze/hang the entire server so I have to hard reset the server. If I unplugged the LAN Cable it wont hang, but if I plugged the LAN Cable, 5 minute later apache will hang and start freezing the entire server

My Question :

1. Is my server specification too low or too old to handle so many
   complicated tasks like that? CPU Utilization show more than 75% Waiting Process at every core. This is the screen shot about what happen when it hangs
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6xL6PTQOOK-cZOXZAYNYFmHbHfUQsQR/view?usp=sharing
2. If I replace my server with faster server, will it solve this problems?
3. Do I need to configure some setting in Apache? Can you help me what should i change in php seting based on my current server specification?
4. I saw a message after I reboot the server. It stated "ROM redundancy detected" Is this mean there is a hardware failure in the server?

Answer (score 0):

It's virtually impossible for us to diagnose your problem with such little information. Here are some steps you can take to get more information and determine what is causing the problem.

Firstly see if the system is reporting what is causing the problem before it's crashing by running this command:

```
dmesg
```

Next check if there is any free disk space on the server by running this command:

```
df -h
```

If it outputs a volume that is 90% or more full, it's likely the disk is full and that's causing problems.

Next I would suggest running these commands to see how much CPU usage occurs or if the server enters "swap hell"

```
htop
```

If for some reason `htop` is not available run `top` instead. You can press <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit either of them while it's running and you can press <kbd>C</kbd> to sort by CPU usage and <kbd>M</kbd> to sort by memory usage.

Next you can check if Apache2 or MySQL (assuming you use MySQL) are throwing any errors:

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
tail /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

There is no reason to upgrade your server unless you have good reason to believe you are currently CPU or Memory bottlenecked or the hardware has failed. A server with 32GB of RAM should be capable of handling tens of thousands of basic reporting tasks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83911/discussion-on-answer-by-kristopher-ives-how-to-determine-what-cause-apache-to-ha).